# How do you keep the windows surface from going to the lock screen?

Tags: windows, microsoft-surface

I like to play music on the internet of my Surface RT. But when I play it, it locks up and pauses the song. How do I keep it unlocked all the time?

Answer (score 1):

How to adjust auto-lock timout on Surface RT:

1. From Start screen, wipe from right to open charms bar.
2. Select Settings > Change PC settings > Users
3. In Users choose your Account and scroll down.
4. Touch Require a password after the display is off for [x min].
5. Enter “power plan settings” into search box from charms bar, you can also adjust the standard power sleep option in TURN OFF THE DISPLAY setting.

From http://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2012/11/how-to-adjust-auto-lock-timout.html

Also try, https://www.google.ca/search?q=turn+surface+tablet+lock+off&rlz=1C1LAVE_enCA373CA377&oq=turn+surface+tablet+lock+off&aqs=chrome.0.57.5248j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8