# Keep Pandora playing when screen times out?

Tags: windows-8, pandora

I use IE in Windows 8 (doesn't matter if Desktop or Metro) to listen to Pandora and when the screen times out (I guess the laptop is going to sleep?) the music stops. I'd like to let the screen time out without stopping the music, like on my phone. Is there an easy fix?

Comment: Does this help http://superuser.com/questions/611597/how-do-you-keep-the-windows-surface-from-going-to-the-lock-screen

Comment: Pretty close. I am using the Surface Pro 3, rather than RT, but I think those settings will be the same. The thing is, I want to let my screen time out without stopping the music, like on an Android device. This saves battery and stuff. I can't imagine why Windows can't do what Android can... but it happens.